# Want to remove specific jars from Gradle fat jar

Tags: java, gradle

My current build.gradle looks like below.

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
       dirs 'lib'
   }
   maven {      
    mavenCentral()
  }

 dependencies {    

  compile "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4", 
          "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4",
          "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4",
          "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.1",             
          "joda-time:joda-time:2.7",


  compile files('../lib/abc.jar')
 }

 jar {
    manifest{
        attributes ("Version" : project.version, "${parent.manifestSectionName}")
        attributes ("Name" : project.name, "${parent.manifestSectionName}")     
    }

    from {
          configurations.runtime.filter( {! (it.name =~ /abc.*\.jar/ )}).collect {
             it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
         }
    }
  }
```

So as you can see I have removed abc.jar at runtime, but in the same way I want to remove few more jars.
In short I want few jars inside of fat jar and needs to exclude few.
So how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The following example may help you. You need to add new configuration - it *extends* compile by default so it will be available during development but will not be included into resulting jar - as joda in the example below.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
  lol
}

dependencies {    

  compile "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4", 
          "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4",
          "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4",
          "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.1"

  lol "joda-time:joda-time:2.7"
}

jar {
  from {
    configurations.runtime.collect {
      it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this approach, but it did not work. It still includes joda-time in fat jar.

Comment: Strange when I run `gradle clean jar` and then extract the jar that was built there're no joda packages.

Comment: I run gradle clean build   ... not sure if there is any difference between jar and build command.

Comment: `build` is just an aggregate task. In this case joda is also missing.

Comment: I tried gradle clean jar command too, but still I see joda- time inside my fat jar.

Comment: Please try `configurations.runtime - configurations.lol` then.

Comment: Have you finally worked it out? Could you please, provide a gist?

Comment: I tried to srite it in below way as suggested by you.

Comment: dependencies {    
  lol "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4"    
    
  compile files('../lib/abc.jar')  
 }
 
 
 jar {
    manifest{
  
  attributes ("Product-Name" : project.name, "${parent.manifestSectionName}")
  attributes ("Product-Display-Name" : project.description, "${parent.manifestSectionName}")
  }
 
 from {
    (configurations.runtime - configurations.lol).collect {
      it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
   }
  }
 }

Comment: But this did not work. its not able to resolve the dependency of commons-logging jar, so throwing an error while building.